# How do I get all values of a key in a perl data structure?

Tags: perl, hash

I want to write a function that will return a list of all “id” values in the data structure below at any level, sorted numerically.  Also if the same value is found in multiple locations in the data structure it should only be included in the returned list once.

```
sub ids {         
    my ($data) = @_;                 
    # Define this function
     }

          my $data = {         
'top' => {
        'window' => {
            'elements' => {
                { id => 44, name => 'link', value => 'www.cnn.com' },
                     { id => 48, name => 'title', value => 'CNN Home Page' },     
                { id => 100, name => 'author', value => 'Admin' }     
            },
                 id => 19
             },
             'cache' => {
                 { id => 199, data => '5' },
                 { id => 40, data => '9' },     
            { id => 100, data => { name => 'author', value => 'Admin' }
 }             },     
        id => 55     },
         id => 1  
     };
          # should print “1, 19, 40, 44, 49, 55, 100, 199”     
print join(', ', ids($data)) . “\n”;
```

Comment: That `$data` does not include a valid Perl data structure, for example, what is the value of `elements`?

Answer (score 1):

Some of data structure should be arrays, not hashes as in OP,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub ids_r {
  my ($data) = @_;

  return map { 
    my $r = ref($data->{$_});
    $r eq "HASH" ? ids_r($data->{$_}) :
      $r         ? map ids_r($_), @{$data->{$_}} :
      $_ eq "id" ? $data->{$_} :
      ();
   } keys %$data;
}
sub ids {        
  my ($data) = @_;
  my %seen;
  return
    sort { $a <=> $b }
    grep !$seen{$_}++, ids_r($data);
}
my $data = {        
  'top' => {
    'window' => {
        'elements' => [
            { id => 44, name => 'link', value => 'www.cnn.com' },
            { id => 48, name => 'title', value => 'CNN Home Page' },
            { id => 100, name => 'author', value => 'Admin' }    
        ],
        id => 19
    },
    'cache' => [
            { id => 199, data => '5' },
            { id => 40, data => '9' },    
            { id => 100, data => { name => 'author', value => 'Admin' } }
    ],    
    id => 55    
  },
  id => 1  
};
print join(', ', ids($data));
```

output

```
1, 19, 40, 44, 48, 55, 100, 199
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple recursive solution. It's pretty easy to see what's going on here.

```
# There is a faster version of `uniq` provided by List::MoreUtils on CPAN.
sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}

sub ids {
    my $val = shift;
    my $ref = ref $val;
    my @r;

    if ($ref eq 'HASH')
    {
        @r = map ids($_), grep ref, values(%$val);
        push @r, $val->{id} if exists $val->{id};
    }

    elsif ($ref eq 'ARRAY')
    {
        @r = map ids($_), grep ref, @$val;
    }

    sort { $a <=> $b } uniq(@r);
}
```

@mpapec provides a similar solution which uses recursion without doing the sorting (the sub called `ids_r` in his answer), and then calls that from a separate wrapper function (the sub called `ids` in his answer) which provides the sorting all at the end. This is more efficient, but arguably more complex. (Indeed, because he had two similarly named functions, the first version of the answer included a mistake which negated the benefit of splitting the sorting out.)

Here's yet another technique, using a queue-based approach instead of recursion. If your data structure is very large, you may find that this works significantly faster.

```
# There is a faster version of `uniq` provided by List::MoreUtils on CPAN.
sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}

sub ids {
    my @r;
    while (@_) {
        my $val = shift;
        my $ref = ref($val);

        if ($ref eq 'HASH')
        {
            push @r, $val->{id} if exists $val->{id};
            push @_, grep ref, values %$val;
        }

        elsif ($ref eq 'ARRAY')
        {
            push @_, grep ref, @$val;
        }
    }

    sort { $a <=> $b } uniq(@r);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps multiple sorts does not add to efficiency.

Comment: @mpapec - same could be said of your answer.

Comment: I'm talking about using `sort` inside recursive function.

Comment: @mpapec, so am I. You have mutually recursive functions. (I assume accidentally.)